# How to invoke a function on click of listitem in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I want to invoke to fetch the contact details after the user clicks on the Contact Name in a List. I am creating the list on the fly as follows:

```
for (var i=0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    $('#contactContainer').append($('<li/>', {   
    }).append($('<a/>', {
                            'href': '#two',
                            'onclick': aclick()
                'data-transition': 'slide',
                    'text': contacts[i].displayName
                })));
    };

    $('ul').listview('refresh');

}
function aclick () {
          alert("Eureka");
}
```

I tried with just alert if the function is called. But it's not called.

Please help me to write function on Click of anchor tag.

Comment: Why can't you just use the `.on()` syntax?

Comment: I tried using it this way 
$("a").on('click',function(){ alert("Eureka");});
But it did not work.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you please include this code in your original question?

Comment: `$('#contactContainer').on('click', 'a', function () { alert('clicked'); });` You're creating anchors dynamically, so you need to attach events this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: you need to bind the click event, while creating the dynamic listview

```
for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {

 $('#contactContainer').append('<li><a data-transition="slide" id="test' + i + '" href="#two">test' + i + '</a></li>');

 $('#test' + i).on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });    
}

$('ul').listview();
```